# How are discriminated unions (e.g. in TS) used in messaging schemes?

Tags: design-patterns, javascript, typescript, unions

In the documentation about discriminated unions in typescript, [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) it says:

> Discriminated unions are useful for more than just talking about
> circles and squares. They’re good for representing any sort of
> messaging scheme in JavaScript, like when sending messages over the
> network (client/server communication), ...

Could some explain an example of a messaging scheme that would make use of it?

Answer (score 2):

Messages are usually serialized into bytes and transmitted over a common channel, so when you receive them on the other end, you just have a string that you deserialize back into a useful type.

If you can, for example, receive both `GET` and `POST` messages over the same channel, you might want to create a `Get` and `Post` class to hold them, so you have a function somewhere like:

```
function deserialize(receivedBytes: string): Get | Post
```

This sort of situation is often handled via inheritance, but union types are more flexible and less coupled. For example, you could specify `Get | Post` in one situation, and `Post | Put` in another situation, and you don't have to personally have control over the source code for `Get`, `Post`, and `Put`, or restrict yourself to exactly one inheritance hierarchy.